How to block the message "You're currently signed in as"?
Is it possible to block, hide, remove or disable the following message which shows for me every time I open a Google Sheets, Google Docs or Google Slides?


Have you tried uBlock Origin? It is mentioned in your tags. Right-clcik an element and select Block element.

The new version with manifest 3 no longer has this option. :(

Noone forces you to use the Manifest v3 version. There are ways to use v2 for a year, still. Maybe they'll get the v3 version into much better state in the meanwhile. Anyways, do you want to just hide the message or the entire popup? As it's unclear. And when does it appear? It's not automatic for me.

It still works in Firefox v. 130, though Manifest V3 is on the way... https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2024/03/13/manifest-v3-manifest-v2-march-2024-update/

FYI: blocking with ublock also disables the Ctrl-F feature in google.

The notification shows because you are signed in to multiple Google accounts in the same web browser. When you open a document, the editor app shows the notification to let you know which identity is being used for recording edit history and such things.
To avoid the notification, sign out of all accounts but one. If you often need to use several accounts, use a different web browser to sign in each account, so that in any given browser you are only signed in one account.
See Fix issues with multiple Google Accounts.
